# how do i show that $x^2+1$ divides $x^{p-1}-1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, modular-arithmetic

$p$ prime integer.

If we are given that $p \equiv 1$ modulo $4$ then $x^2+1$ divides $x^{p-1}-1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$. I can show this by considering the cyclic subgroup $\langle g \rangle$of $\mathbb{Z}_p^\times$ of order $4$:
$g^4=1 \implies g^2=-1 \implies x^2+1=(x-g)(x+g)$, which divides $x^{p-1}-1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$.

How can I show it in another method (with perhaps some ring theory)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z=F$ you have Fermat's little theorem which says that

> $$x^p-x=x(x-1)\ldots (x-(p-1)).$$

This means there must be $1\le i\le p-1$ such that $i^2\equiv -1\mod p$ since $F[x]$ is a UFD. But then we know about squares based on the Legendre symbol so that $p\equiv 1\mod 4$ iff $(-1)^{(p-1)/2}\equiv 1\mod p$, i.e. there is such an $i$ iff $p\equiv 1\mod 4$.

**Addendum based on comments:** The reason UFD is so essential is because having one polynomial dividing the other means that it must be the product of a subset of the larger one's irreducible components. Since $x^{p-1}-1=(x-1)(x-2)\ldots (x-(p-1))$ if $(x^2+1)|(x^{p-1}-1)$ it must be that it is the product of two of the linear factors of the RHS, but then since $(x-a)(x-b)=x^2+1$ we have $a=-b$ and $a^2=-1$.

Alternatively, since $|F^\times|=p-1$ is cyclic, there is an element of order $4$ iff $p\equiv 1\mod 4$, which is slightly more expedient if you know that part of the algebra.

Comment: Sorry I don't get why there is an $i$ with $i^2 \equiv -1$ mod $p$ since $F[x]$ is a UFD

Comment: @sammy123 Having something divide something else means they have gcd = the smaller degree one of the two, so the roots of $x^{p-1}-1$ must include numbers $\pm i$ where $i$ has the listed properties, since the roots of $x^{p-1}-1$ are **exactly** the numbers $1, 2,\ldots, p-1$ by Fermat. See my edit for further details.